# Pushing Django project from virtualenv to github

Tags: python, django, git, virtualenv

I'm working in  virtualenv on a small Django project that needs to be shared on github and then cloned and installed on an Apache server from there. I have never used virtualenv in conjunction with github before. Ordinarily I'd set up the local git repository on the same level as the manage.py file. However, there are several virtualenv directories I don't really want (bin, lib, include etc) on that level along with my needed apps and template directories etc.

So, what is the way to create  a github repository in this case. Is there a way to be selective and filter out the virtualenv stuff.

Answer (score 6):

This is the directory structure I follow -

```
/path/to/application/
|-- project
|   |-- projectname
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- local_settings.py
|   |   |-- settings.py
|   |   |-- urls.py
|   |   `-- wsgi.py
|   |-- appone
|   |   |-- admin.py
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- models.py
|   |   |-- tests.py
|   |   `-- views.py
|   `-- manage.py
`-- venv
    |-- bin
    |-- include
    |-- lib
    `-- local
```

You can easily create a Django project inside a directory called `project` like this -

```
$ django-admin.py startproject projectname project
```

And initiate virtualenv inside a directory called `venv` like this -

```
$ virtualenv venv
```

Then you can just go ahead and `git init` inside `/project`. This keeps the virtualenv outside the scope of your git repository.

Otherwise, if you want to stick to your current structure, you can create a `.gitignore` file and mentione `bin`, `lib`, `include` etc there.

Comment: Do you use freeze > requirements.txt ? If yes then where do you place it ?

Answer (score 1):

When working with a virtual environment, the common practice is to include the virtual environment folder in your `.gitignore` file. More on how to use this git feature [here](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/).

TL;DR: whatever you put in your .gitignore file will get ignored by git. Said file (`.gitignore`) resides in the same directory as your git repository.

Example of such a file which ignores any compiled source code (.pyc), compressed file (.zip, .rar, .tar), logs and databases (.db, .log, .sql) and virtual environment files (Scripts, Lib, Include) and whole folders (env - name of my virtualenv folder):

```
# Compiled source #
###################
*.com
*.class
*.dll
*.exe
*.o
*.so
*.pyc

# Packages #
############
*.7z
*.dmg
*.gz
*.iso
*.jar
*.rar
*.tar
*.zip

# Logs and databases #
######################
*.db
*.log
*.sql
*.sqlite

# virtualenv generated files #
##############################
Scripts
Lib
Include

# virtualenv folders #
######################
env
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the Github docs on [ignoring files](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files) - it basically amounts to putting a `.gitignore` file in your project, with a list of patterns that match files you don't want git to manage.